# What is the root cause of the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-native

One can find this error type in React, Angular, React-Native. I am able to find a lots of questions with this error type but I am curious as to when does the console throw this error?

*Edit:*
Can you explain me with the following reference to react-native

```
export class EventList extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <FlatList 
            data={[{key: 'a'},{key: 'b'}]}
            renderItem={({ itemObject }) => <Text>{itemObject.key}</Text>}
        />
    );
}
}
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code that throws this error. In a React context it is often that you don't take asynchronous loading into consideration, so you try to do `notLoadedObj.key` and try to read `key` from `undefined`.

Comment: Well, I'm passing data as a prop in <Flatlist> in react-native

Comment: The item is named `item`, not `itemObject`

Answer (score 4):

When the parent object or array is `undefined`, for example, if you call `a.b` or `a[b]`, but a is undefined

Comment: Thanks for the info, can you please explain it with reference to the edit in the question?

Comment: You need to show the code where you use data. I assume it was data[something...].key or so?

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when you try to access a property `key` on `undefined`.

This happens in your `renderItem` function since the item object is called `item` and not `itemObject`. Change to `item` and it will work as expected.

```
export class EventList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={[{ key: "a" }, { key: "b" }]}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you've declared your `renderItem` function.

You have:

```
render() {
    return (
        <FlatList 
            data={[{key: 'a'},{key: 'b'}]}
            renderItem={({ itemObject }) => <Text>{itemObject.key}</Text>}
        />
    );
}
```

Specifically `({ itemObject })` means "deconstruct the argument passed to `renderItem` and from that extract the property `itemObject`".

However [the signature of renderItem](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#renderitem) is:

```
renderItem({ item: Object, index: number, separators: { highlight: Function, unhighlight: Function, updateProps: Function(select: string, newProps: Object) } }) => ?React.Element
```

As you can see the object passed as a parameter does not contain `itemObject` therefore destructuring it and extracting `itemObject` will result in `itemObject` being undefined.

You have 2 options:

Either do what the example states exactly:

```
       <FlatList 
            data={[{key: 'a'},{key: 'b'}]}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
```

If you insist on renaming the default member you can do:

```
       <FlatList 
            data={[{key: 'a'},{key: 'b'}]}
            renderItem={({ item: itemObject }) => <Text>{itemObject.key}</Text>}
        />
```